# Join comma with space in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a string of sequence say "aby,abraham,issac,rebecca,job,david,daniel" now I need to add space after the comma.

I bind the value using `ng-bind` and display the result using `ng-show`. I'm unable to use join as it is received as array from the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use filter to do this task

```
.filter('commaSpace', [function () {
    return function (str) {
      return str.replace(',/g', ', ');
    };
  }])
```

Comment: <td style="max-width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word;" ng-if="users.name!='-'">  
<span ng-bind="Username"
                                              ng-show="!users.name"></span>
                                        <span ng-bind="users.name"
                                              ng-show="users.name"></span>

Comment: can i add this filter in my first td

Comment: <td style="max-width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word;" ng-if="users.name!='-'"> <span ng-bind="Username" ng-show="!users.name"></span> <span ng-bind="(users.name | commaSpace)" ng-show="users.name"></span>

Comment: Yes u can use it in ng-bind

Comment: With str.replace(',', ', ') you just replace first ocurrence.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to hard code this values "aby,abraham,issac,rebecca,job,david,daniel" in ng-bind = "Username" to the changes

Comment: Thank you all so much 2 Manish Balodia @ Jonhid

Answer (score 0):

You can directly bind like this,

```
<span ng-bind="users.name.split(',').join(', ')" ng-show="users.name"></span>
```

No need to create filters.

To initialize the value, use `ng-init` directive to hardcode the value to Username

> ng-init="Username='aby,abraham,issac,rebecca,job,david,daniel'"